# How to apply a CSS class to a Select using Materialize and SimpleForm in Rail 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a class to stick in the right spot using SimpleForm and Materialize with Select inputs.

The Materialize simpleform wrappers from this gem (https://github.com/jamesfwz/materialize-form) work great for most fields but if I want a field to load with the Invalid class for a Select field, I cant get it right.

Heres a working example say with a text field.
In my view:

```
<%= f.input :suburb,  input_html: {class: "invalid"} %>
```

Output:

```
<div class="input-field col string optional">
  <input class="string optional invalid" type="text" ....>Suburb</label></div>
```

Which correctly appears with its invalid formatting.

When I try it with a select input, I can't get the class in the right spot. Ie. the associated Materialize text input it creates using js.

Using wrapper_html option in my view:

```
<%= f.input :state,              
        collection: ["VIC","NSW","TAS","SA","ACT","WA"], 
        wrapper_html: { class: 'invalid' }
```

Which puts the class on the outer wrapper, but not the visible text element:

```
<div class="input-field col select optional invalid">
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true">
      <ul id="select-..." class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0">
        <li id="select-options-..." tabindex="0" class="selected"><span>
```

Which doesn't show correctly.

I've tried the input_html option;

```
<%= f.input :state,              
        collection: ["VIC","NSW","TAS","SA","ACT","WA"], 
        input_html: { class: 'invalid' }
```

Which puts the class on the Select element, but not the visible text element

```
<div class="input-field col select optional ">
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <input class="select-dropdown dropdown-trigger" type="text" readonly="true">
       <ul id="select-options-..." class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0">
         <li ...</li></ul>
           <select class="select optional invalid" name="...">
             <option value=""></option>
```

I've tried the straight class option;

```
<%= f.input :state,              
        collection: ["VIC","NSW","TAS","SA","ACT","WA"], 
        class: 'invalid'
```

Which doesn't have the class appear anywhere (unsurprisingly)

Lastly, I've tried the html_options option hoping it would get passed to the collection_select method and get picked up by Materialize

```
<%= f.input :state,              
        collection: ["VIC","NSW","TAS","SA","ACT","WA"], 
        class: 'invalid'
```

Which doesn't have the class appear anywhere (even more unsurprisingly!)

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [option_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

```
invalid_value = "NSW"
values = ["VIC","NSW","TAS","SA","ACT","WA"].map { |v| v == invalid_value ? [v, class: 'invalid'] : v  }
=> ["VIC", ["NSW", {:class=>"invalid"}], "TAS", "SA", "ACT", "WA"]
```

then

```
<%= f.select :state, options_for_select(values, invalid_value), include_blank: true %>
```

**Edit:**

To add class to Materialize generated select

```
<%= form.input :state, collection:  ["VIC","NSW","TAS","SA","ACT","WA"], input_html: { class: "invalid" } %>
```

Add add some JS
This should run after Materialize drop down is generated

```
$('select.invalid').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass('invalid')
})
```

Comment: Thanks PGill but the "invalid" class is a materialize class that applies to the input/select. What I wanted was the whole select input to have the invalid class applied not just an option. Materialize creates a text input which shows the selection. My issue is that this js created text field, does not inherit the class from the underlying select.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Cheers PGill, I had hoped I would be able to get simpleform to feed the class nicely to Materialize but a bit of unobtrusive js is a workaround. I'll probably use a data-attribute to avoid any unexpected behaviour down the track from my selector. Thanks for your time.